# ExpressionEngine session cookie not being set on login in some browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, cookies, expressionengine

I'm using ExpressionEngine for a fairly high traffic site.

I have almost exactly the same setup at my office as I do at home. I use chrome most often on both machines.

Although I have no issues at the office, at home I am unable to login to my site successfully. Specifically the session cookie isn't set. This only occurs in IE and Chrome (as far as I've tested) and the cookie is set properly in Firefox. I used to be able to login through Chrome at home but haven't been able since I upgraded to Windows 8.

I've tried changing the cookie settings and even setting a rule specifically for the site but have had no success.

One of our staff members had a similar issue with her machine and I was never able to solve it but I would really like to figure out what's going.

Comment: Most of the questions I asked were facebook api related and there was no real answer because it was just a bug with facebook. The cookie session setting code is internal to the cms which is why I listed it but I'll check the core and post the code in a bit.

Comment: Well then answer the questions with this solution and accept them. That way it helps the community.

Comment: What? Anyways the cms is using the setcookie function in php. I have some trepidation about the issue being the cms code since it works nearly across the board except in this instance (aside from the one coworker I've never been sent a bug report about it).

Comment: I meant go to your old questions, the ones where you know the solution (facebook bug) and post a answer. That way others can benefit from your findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting my system clock to the correct timezoned fixed the issue. My clock was set to the incorrect timezone and had been manually advanced a few hours. I believe this expired the cookies as soon as they were created.